# react navigation two navigators on one screen nested in StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I got one screen where I need to get `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` and `createBottomTabNavigator` it is nested in `createStackNavigator`.

So I click on button on HomeScreen and StackNavigator navigates me to screen where is 
`createBottomTabNavigator` primary navigation and `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` is different for each screen in `createBottomTabNavigator`

So it should be

```
createStackNavigator
    createBottomTabNavigator
        createMaterialTopTabNavigator
           SomeTabBarScreen
           SomeTabBarScreen
        createMaterialTopTabNavigator //if I click on icon in BottomNavigator to navigate on another screen I want different TopNavigator
           SomeTabBarScreen
           SomeTabBarScreen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just write out some pseudo code here, but you can nest stacks like so:

```
const FirstMatTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({//Routes here});
const SecondMatTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({//Routes here});

const TabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
    FirstTab: FirstMatTab,
    SecondTab: SecondMatTab
});

const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
    Tab: TabNav,
})
```

This means you can just call  in your render function the component you want it rendered in.

Comment: Thank you very much. As soon as my project is getting little bit more complicated I had problem to figure it by myself.

Comment: Not to worry, I had a similar issue in my project so I was quite happy to share what solved my issue. Glad it has helped you! :)

Comment: @swonder can you check here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766833/how-to-handle-two-navigator-in-react-navigation