# How to Handle Two navigator in react navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

***Hello Guys***,

I have some issue with **React navigation V3**,
In my app, I have an Authentication step to Entering to Home Screen and it doesn't have a Drawer Navigation as a default, it will be Stack Navigator

> Splash => Sign-up => Sign-in => Home

And in The Home Screen must Contain a Drawer Navigation And StackNavigation at the same time.

I'm Write one file named as a Route.js contain all of my Navigations,

But Now
**createAppContainer** just accept on arg like this I think.

`export default  MyApp = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);`

and I want to use my other StackNavigator Not Contained in a Drawer, how to solve this problem?

### **Here is a Route.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our code.
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

//Import required react-navigation component 
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';

//Import all the screens for Drawer/ Sidebar
import Splash from "../screens/Splash";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import SignUp from "../screens/SignUp";
import SignIn from "../screens/SignIn";
import ForgetPassword from "../screens/ForgetPassword";
import Order from "../screens/Order";
import MapApp from "../screens/MapApp";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

//Navigation Drawer Structure for all screen
class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {
  //Structure for the navigatin Drawer
  toggleDrawer = () => {
    //Props to open/close the drawer
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          <Icon name="md-menu" size={30} color='#009' style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const Route = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Screen1 will be indexed here
  Splash: {
    screen: Splash,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  },
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignUp,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      // header: null
      title: "Sign Up",
      headerLeft: null,
      headerTintColor: "#0496FF",
      headerStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "white"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#0496FF",
        textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25,
        justifyContent: "center"
      }
    })
  },
  SignIn: {
    screen: SignIn,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Sign In",
      headerRight: <View />,
      headerTintColor: "#0496FF",
      headerStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "white"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#0496FF",
        textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25,
        justifyContent: "center"
      }
    }
  },
  ForgetPassword: {
    screen: ForgetPassword,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Forget Password",
      headerRight: <View />,
      headerTintColor: "#0496FF",
      headerStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "white"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#0496FF",
        textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25,
        justifyContent: "center"
      }
    }
  },
  MapApp: {
    screen: MapApp,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Map",
      headerRight: <View />,
      headerLeft: <View />,
      headerTintColor: "#0496FF",
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
        borderBottomColor: "white",
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#0496FF",
        textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25,
        justifyContent: "center"
      }
    }
  }
});


//Stack Navigator for First Option of Navigation Drawer
const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        elevation: 0,
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

//Stack Navigator for Second Option of Navigation Drawer
const Screen2_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Screen2 will be indexed here
  Order: {
    screen: Order,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Order',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

//Drawer Navigator for the Navigation Drawer / Sidebar
const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
  //Drawer Optons and indexing
  Screen1: {
    //Title
    screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="ios-home" size={30} color='#009' />
      ),
    },

  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Order',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="ios-list-box" size={30} color='#009' />
      ),
    },
  },

});


export default MyApp = createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);
```

### **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MyApp from './src/navigations/Route'
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyApp />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You must wrap every stack with the drawer. Then use the drawer as the root navigation for the parent stack.

Comment: As per your example, if the home component is a stack wrap it with a drawer component and then import the drawer which contains the stack.

Comment: are you mean like this,
`
const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
  Route: Route,
....
....
})
`

Comment: @Javan_Poirier sorry I don't understand what you mean really :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question so well, But what I suggest is to make each navigator in a different file like for example your `StackNavigation` in a file called "firstActivity_StackNavigator.js" and then you need to export the navigator as follow:

```
...
const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        elevation: 0,
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});
export default FirstActivity_StackNavigator;
```

Then in your main navigator you just import whatever navigators you want

```
import FirstActivity_StackNavigator from "./firstActivity_StackNavigator.js"
import Screen2_StackNavigator from "./screen2_StackNavigator.js"

const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
  //Drawer Optons and indexing
  Screen1: {
    //Title
    screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="ios-home" size={30} color='#009' />
      ),
    },

  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Order',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="ios-list-box" size={30} color='#009' />
      ),
    },
  },

});
...
```

Hopefully this answer your question

Comment: If you have time, can you check here,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55775071/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-nearby-users-in-an-react-native-app-based-on-firebase

Comment: @DevAS You are welcome, please if this resolve the issue make sure to mark it as done

Comment: @DevAS I will check this as well

Comment: sure but please don't forget to check my another Q, I'm really stuck.